# How to connect vscode debug to karma

Tags: webpack, visual-studio-code, jasmine, karma-runner, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to setup the vscode debugger to connect to karma.
I've tried two different routes
One is https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=raagh.angular-karma-test-explorer
And the other is the direct method of just doing an attach in the launch.json
But the closest I got with either solution was that I could 'run' the tests from vscode, but debugging them resulted in faulty inspection data and the breakpoints being hit out of order. My *assumption* is my sourcemaps need modification.

Here is what I currently have.
Karma

```
/**
 * @author: @AngularClass
 */

module.exports = function (config) {
  var testWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.test.js')({ env: 'test' });

  var configuration = {

    /**
     * Base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (e.g. files, exclude).
    */
    basePath: '',

    /**
     * Frameworks to use
     *
     * available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
     */
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    /**
     * List of files to exclude.
    */
    exclude: [],

    client: {
      captureConsole: true
    },

    /**
     * List of files / patterns to load in the browser
     *
     * we are building the test environment in ./spec-bundle.js
     */
    files: [
      { pattern: './config/spec-bundle.js', watched: false },
      { pattern: './src/assets/**/*', watched: false, included: false, served: true, nocache: false }
    ],

    /**
     * By default all assets are served at http://localhost:[PORT]/base/
     */
    proxies: {
      "/assets/": "/base/src/assets/"
    },

    /**
     * Preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
     * available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
     */
    preprocessors: { './config/spec-bundle.js': ['coverage', 'webpack', 'sourcemap'] },

    /**
     * Webpack Config at ./webpack.test.js
     */
    webpack: testWebpackConfig,

    coverageReporter: {
      type: 'in-memory'
    },

    remapCoverageReporter: {
      'text-summary': null,
      json: './coverage/coverage.json',
      html: './coverage/html'
    },

    /**
     * Webpack please don't spam the console when running in karma!
     */
    webpackMiddleware: {
      /**
       * webpack-dev-middleware configuration
       * i.e.
       */
      noInfo: true,
      /**
       * and use stats to turn off verbose output
       */
      stats: {
        /**
         * options i.e.
         */
        chunks: false
      }
    },

    /**
     * Test results reporter to use
     *
     * possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
     * available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
     */
    reporters: ['mocha', 'coverage', 'remap-coverage'],

    /**
     * Web server port.
     */
    port: 9876,

    /**
     * enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
     */
    colors: true,

    /**
     * Level of logging
     * possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
     */
    logLevel: config.LOG_WARN,

    /**
     * enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
     */
    autoWatch: true,

    /**
     * start these browsers
     * available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
     */
    browsers: [
      'ChromeHeadless',
      'ChromeDebugging'
    ],

    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeTravisCi: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-gpu']
      },
      AWSCodebuild: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-gpu', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
      },
      ChromeDebugging : {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--disable-gpu', '--remote-debugging-port=9222'],
        debug: true
      }
    },

    /**
     * Continuous Integration mode
     * if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
     */
    singleRun: false
  };

  if (process.env.TRAVIS) {
    configuration.browsers = [
      'ChromeTravisCi'
    ];
  }
  if (process.env.CODEBUILD_BUILD_ARN) {
    configuration.browsers = [
      'AWSCodebuild'
    ];
  }

  config.set(configuration);
};
```

webpack.test.js

```
const { ContextReplacementPlugin, DefinePlugin } = require('webpack');
const helpers = require('./helpers');

const ENV = (process.env.ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test');
const CONFIG = {
  merchantMonitoringHost: 'https://2k0nuwkvc4.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev',
  auditHost: ' https://ocbdkvw7e2.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev',
  accountServiceHost: 'http://localhost:4000/api',
  privateHost: 'http://localhost:3000'
};

module.exports = () => {
  return {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    mode: 'development',
    stats: 'minimal',
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
      modules: [helpers.root('src'), 'node_modules']
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.js$/,
          loader: 'source-map-loader',
          exclude: [
            helpers.root('node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5'),
            helpers.root('node_modules/primeng'),
            helpers.root('node_modules/rxjs-compat')
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
              query: {
                /**
                 * Use inline sourcemaps for "karma-remap-coverage" reporter
                 */
                sourceMap: false,
                inlineSourceMap: true,
                compilerOptions: {
                  /**
                   * Remove TypeScript helpers to be injected
                   * below by DefinePlugin
                   */
                  removeComments: true
                }
              }
            },
            'angular2-template-loader'
          ],
          exclude: [/\.e2e\.ts$/]
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          loader: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
          exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [
            'raw-loader',
            'sass-loader',
            {
              loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
              options: {
                context: helpers.root('.'),
                resources: [
                  // The order of the files matters here!  Be careful when changing this order!
                  helpers.root('src/styles/_variables.scss'),
                  helpers.root('src/styles/_fonts.scss'),
                  helpers.root('src/styles/_buttons.scss'),
                  helpers.root('src/styles/_forms.scss'),
                  helpers.root('src/styles/_tables.scss'),
                  helpers.root('src/styles/_ng2tooltip.scss'),
                  helpers.root('src/styles/_helpers.scss'),
                  helpers.root('src/styles/styles.scss')
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          loader: 'raw-loader',
          exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
          use: 'file-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.(svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
          use: 'file-loader'
        },
        {
          // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21560
          test: /[\/\\]@angular[\/\\]core[\/\\].+\.js$/,
          parser: { system: true }
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new DefinePlugin({
        ENV: JSON.stringify(ENV),
        CONFIG: JSON.stringify(CONFIG),
        'process.env': {
          ENV: JSON.stringify(ENV),
          NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(ENV)
        }
      }),
      new ContextReplacementPlugin(
        /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
        helpers.root('src'), // location of your src
        {}
      )
    ],
    performance: {
      hints: false
    },
    node: {
      global: true,
      process: false,
      crypto: 'empty',
      module: false,
      clearImmediate: false,
      setImmediate: false
    }
  };
};
```

tsconfig.webpack.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "src/custom-typings.d.ts"
    ],
    "types": [
      "hammerjs",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.e2e.ts"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "./compiled",
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [  {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Debug Unit Tests",
      "address": "localhost",
      "port": 9222,
      "pathMapping": {
          "/" : "${workspaceRoot}",
          "/base": "${workspaceRoot}"
      },
      "sourceMaps": true
    }]
}
```